# How to build JNI DLL that calls function from another DLL? - JNI, Gradle

Tags: java, c, gradle, dll, java-native-interface

I have actualised the sample given on IDEA website's guide on JNI in this [repo](https://github.com/lilvadim/GradleJniSample) (you can see fork there) and now it runs with modern JDK and JUnit Tests even on my aarch64 Mac (hope it runs anywhere else). But I do not really understand what is going on in `build.gradle` in `hello` Gradle subproject folder. I can recognise compiler arguments there, but include options are set in separate methods, which gets me confused.

My aim is to have just wrapper C-file that doing `dlopen`(or its Windows' alternative) and runs some function from dynamic library.

E.g.

```
<ProjectRoot>/hello/src/main/c/ wrapper-with-JNI-call-convensions.c 
                                libsomelib.dylib
                                libsomelib.so
                                somelib.dll

Calls looks like this: Java -[JNI]-> wrapper.dll -> somelib.dll
                                     ^    ^    ^
                                     |    |    |
                         building wrapper.c using Gradle to this
```

So I have successfully managed to get JNI working (while not changing `build.gradle` from sample) if I just run build  with two C source files (wrapper that uses JNI and C source code of my library). Then I built `dylib` using macOS built-in `clang` compiler and wrote proper (I guess) `dlopen` and `dlsym` code. But when I build project I get NULL returned from `dlopen` call.

I have tried to add some arguments to the `build.gradle` that used to compile binary that uses dynamic library, but it did not help.

My test running exits here:

```
// my wrapper
void* dlHandle = dlopen("libsomelib.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (dlHandle == NULL) {
        printf("DLL NOT OPENED !!!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
```

I know I have to write proper platform-dependent calls in my wrapper, it's not a big deal for me.

So can you tell me how I can properly get this working using Gradle? Remember that goal is to have just JNI-ready `*.c` wrapper and just dynamic linked libraries `*.so & *.dylib & *.dll` in my case.

**Update:** I've decided not to use Gradle, I use VSCode `tasks.json`, it is like 20 times more intuitive. I will write my approach as self-answer.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is something you are looking for: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo018, but it does similar thing.

Comment: @Oo.oO you're right. That is what I need, but I've tried to pass these arguments like this `compileTask.compilerArgs.addAll(["-x", "c","-Wl,-rpath, @loader_path" ])` and it does not work. Also I don't know why in sample there are not any args for building library, there are just `-x c` and include-paths arguments and it somehow building that dylib.

Comment: `-rpath` on macOS might be tricky. You have so set the library name as well. This is why, in the sample, you have: `-install_name libReloadLib.$(EXT)`. If you have the library that already exists, it might require changing its name. You can find sample here: `https://www.owsiak.org/setting-up-googletest-on-macos/`

Comment: Another question here is. Do you have to call `dlopen` at all? Maybe you can simply follow this pattern: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023 - in this case you simply link everything all together and you don't have to call `dlopen` at all.

Comment: @Oo.oO I have not practicing building libraries on macOS and I thought that `dlopen/LoadLibrary` is needed to use functions from dynamic linked libraries on every OS. But in fact I can just compile `.c` and `.dylib` on macOS and just use function defined in header?

Comment: Yes - exactly. You can simply provide your library as shared library installed system wide (in that case you just link with it and use header) or you can bundle library with your app. But here, be careful with all the `@rpath` etc. It might be tricky. There is another sample how to set it: https://www.owsiak.org/setting-up-googletest-on-macos/ - you can learn there how to setup and alter `@rpath` in already existing library.

Comment: @Oo.oO But if I do something like `clang wrapper.c libsome.dylib` the compiler says that in can't compile a `dylib` which is true because it's already not a `.c` file. Maybe I don't get options in the recipe right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it running you can try following:

```
> cc -g -shared -fpic wrapper.c -L. -lsome -o libwrapper.dylib
```

I assume that you have `libsome.dylib` inside current directory. Then you can load `libwrapper.dylib` inside `JNI` and it refer to this another lib: `libsome.dylib`

**Update**

Let's say you have these two files:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void anotherFunction () {
  // we are printing message from another C file
  printf ("Hello from another function!\n");
}
```

and corresponding header file

```
#ifndef another_h__
#define another_h__

void anotherFunction (void)
#endif                          // another_h__
```

You can build a library out of it, by calling something like this:

```
cc -shared -fpic recipeNo023_AnotherFunction.c -o libanother.dylib
```

This will be equivalent of your: `somelib`

Then, we can have something like this:

```
#include "recipeNo023_redux_HelloWorld.h"

void anotherFunction ();

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo023_redux_HelloWorld_displayMessage
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {

  printf ("Hello world!\n");
  /* We are calling function from another source */

  anotherFunction ();
}
```

We declare function and use it. Name will be resolved later, during linking phase.

Now, you can compile your `wrapper` lib. In this sample it's `HelloWorld`.

```
cc -shared -fpic recipeNo023_redux_HelloWorld.c -L. -lanother
```

Now, inside `JNI`, all you do is:

```
System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
```

Due to the fact `HelloWorld` was linked with shared library `another` it will have access to its symbols. So, you don't need to use `dlopen`.

Try the sample (there is even Docker based file so you don't have to struggle with setting up environment).

Comment: So,
- do I need `dlopen` in this case? 
- do I need header of function defined in libsome?

Comment: You don't have to `dlopen` here.

Comment: Actually, I've decided to get rid of this Gradle build, because I didn't figured out how to properly pass arguments through this. I've build like you said with some additional args and it works! Thanks! But can I ask if Linux `.so` can be used same way? I mean without `dlopen` at all. And where can I read about what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same way. Take a look into `Makefiles`. You will notice that the very same code works on both: `macOS` and `Linux`. The only difference is the file extension: `so` for `Linux` and `dylib` for `macOS`. Also, in some cases there are small adjustments to arguments, but mechanism is quite similar.

Comment: As I understand wrapper lib is being dynamically loaded into a JVM via `dlopen` but another lib is not dynamically loaded into a wrapper, right?

Comment: Yes, somewhere in the guts of `JVM` there will be `dlopen` that opens your library. Then, dependencies are resolved based on symbols and library dependencies. In general, you can always check whether your wrapper can "see" the shared library by calling `otool` on macOS or `ld` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oo.oO mentioned [this](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo018) recipe is exactly what I need. It's dynamic load approach and it works on Mac and Linux. Also, as he mentioned there is static linking approach which is demonstrated [here](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023) and in his answer.

I would also add some compiler options into this:

```sh
-O3                     \   # for optimisation of speed
-x c                    \   # to explicitly set language to C, in my case
-fvisibility=default    \   # to export only that I need (read below)
-arch x86_64            \   # option ONLY for macOS built-in clang in case you want build Intel binary on Silicon Mac
```

In lib's source code you should also define

```c
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

and then write it in header before each function declaration or in source file before each definition for functions that you want to be used from outside or lib.

e.g.

```c
// somelib.h
EXPORT void somefunc(int a, int b);

// somelib.c
#include "somelib.h" // somelib.c and somelib.h in same directory
void somefunc(int a, int b) { ... }
```

OR

```c
// in case you don't want to use header (I recommend to use)
// somelib.c
EXPORT void somefunc(int a, int b) { ... }
```

This answer will be advanced with Windows cases later.

## Summary

#### macOS+`clang` & Linux+`gcc`

- [Dynamic load of DLL](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo018)
- [Static linking DLLs](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023)